# javascript code onscroll in blazor not working

Tags: javascript, blazor, blazor-webassembly

In a Blazor app I have a script.js file in wwwroot/js/script.js.

The javascript should call the scrollFunction while scrolling inside the app, but "Hello World" never comes up.

**Why this javascript function is not called when I scroll up and down the page?**

```js
window.onscroll = function () { scrollFunction() };

function scrollFunction() {
    window.alert("Hello World");
}
```

At the wwwroot/index.html I call this js file:

```html
... <body>
      <script src="js/script.js"></script> ...
```

at the _Imports.razor I added..

```js
@using Microsoft.JSInterop
```

PS:
When I set in index.html

```
 <head> ...<script>window.alert("Hello You");</script> ... </head>
```

or

```
<script>onmousedown = (event) => { window.alert("Click") };</script>
```

I get the Message.

But when I set

```
<script>window.onscroll = function () { window.alert("Hello World") };</script>
```

or

```
<script>onscroll = (event) => { window.alert("Scroll") };</script>
```

and scroll, I never get the message. **The Problem is only with onscroll.**

Comment: Can you verify you are actually correctly including the script? Shoudn't it be "/js/script.js" instead of "js/script.js"?

Comment: I'm sure "js/script.js" is fine because I tried "/js/script.js" and the auto completion suggest that path "js/script.js".

Comment: Can you verify that in the developer console? (f12)

Comment: Make sure to clear browser cache by holding down Ctrl and pressing F5. Older version of `index.html` could be cached without the script tag. Also this is not related to JSInterop. You are not calling js from c#, just plain javascript, so `@using Microsoft.JSInterop` is not relevant to your problem.

Comment: If you put the code directly in the `<script></script>` tag does it work? If it does then it's most likely the reference to it.

Comment: The console does not give informations. 
Ctrl + F5 does not help. 
Setting the code straight inside <script></script> also does not work.